# How to make powershell start as administrator when launched via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

I've set up a shortcut on my Desktop for Powershell so that I can quickly launch it anywhere/anytime.

[image: shortcut options]

Is there a way to require it to launch as administrator? Where I'd normally set it to be run as an administrator, I've got it grayed out:

[image: compatibility options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- On the *"Shortcut"* tab (your first screenshot), click on the *"Advanced..."* button.
- Click to enable *"Run as Administrator"*.

[image]

Now whenever you use that shortcut it will run PowerShell as Administrator, regardless of whether you clicked it or used the assigned keyboard shortcut.